# I want my HTML 5 <video>

Tags: video, browser, html

I'm very excited about the new [HTML 5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html5_video.asp) video tag, which lets website authors embed videos in web pages without using Flash or Silverlight. I'd like to see some more of what's possible for this coming web feature. Do you have any:

- Comprehensive lists of what browsers support HTML 5 video (I understand that the latest Firefox supports it with Ogg but not h.264)
- Good online demonstrations of html 5 video?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150577/which-browser-has-the-best-support-for-html-5-currently) question on stackoverflow it looks like Safari (webkit - H264),Opera (Presto) and Firefox (Gecko - Ogg) are the three currently supporting the HTML5 Video tag. Full comparison on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML_5)).

I also found a few HTML5 video demo sites...

- [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/html5)
- [dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/openvideodemo)
- [HTML 5 Video Element Examples](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2008/10/html-5-video-element-examples.html)

Answer (score 5):

On [When can I use...](http://a.deveria.com/caniuse/#feat=video)

The following browsers are supported to support the HTML 5 video tag:

- Safari 3.2+ (H.264 only)
- Firefox 3.5+ (Ogg Theora only - 4.0 brings WebM support)
- Opera 10.* (Ogg Theora, 10.5 brought WebM)
- Chrome 3.0+ (Ogg Theora, H.264, WebM came around Chrome 5.0)

Notably Internet Explorer has no HTML 5 support in IE 8. Microsoft is currently looking into yet but has yet to commit (understandably) to what bits of HTML 5 will be implemented for IE 9.

Because of the lack of consensus on the codec that should be implemented by browsers (free and open source versus patent liability worries) that part of the HTML5 spec was [dropped](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-June/020620.html).